# Give task priority android

Tags: android, scroll, ticker, thread-priority

I have an android application where i have some scrolling text ticker that is implemented via javascript and loaded in a web view. It is working fine but whenever the processor is busy, (like i have many timers in my application for updates, slide show, camera image processing etc) the ticker stops for a moment and then resumes.

Can I give the web view a higher priority so that its operations are not hindered by other processes?